# Display the actual index field

Tags: solr

At the moment I am researching what the best configuration for Solr is to fit the scope of my application. It involves a lot of testing and I was wondering if I can display what Solr saves as index. I.e. I want to see the tokenized, stemmed, lower cased, etc. version of my documents. Is there any way Solr will provide this information?

Thank you
Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Luke: http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Solr also has a Luke handler built-in: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! It is important to use a newer version of Luke though (at least for me it was). Those can be found here: [http://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/list](http://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/list)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Solr Analysis which is provided on Solr admin interface. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdminGUI

When on the analysis page, just putting the 'field type' or 'field name' you want the analysis on and put in any field value. Solr Analysis will show you what each Filter/Tokenizer is doing and how exactly does your content look after each step. Its great for testing and debugging.

You can do the same on a query if you have set such analyzers (tokenizers/filters) on your query as well in the schema.

Hope this helps.