# How can we retrieve tokens of a particular property from search engine?

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco

Community version. When contents are added in Alfresco search engine tokenizes properties (name, description) and stores it in indexes. I would like to know if there a way by which we could retrieve a list of those keywords associated with particular content?

**Ex.. Fetch me tokens from "Name" of "abc.txt" content**

I see there are API's exposed by SolR to get overall status of indexes and to fix transactions, but nothing which meets my needs.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience, needed to find out what the tokenizer was doing about indexes because a particular file name was not found during search.

I finally used [Luke Lucene index toolbox](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) which is:

> Luke is a handy development and diagnostic tool, which accesses
>   already existing Lucene indexes and allows you to display and modify
>   their content in several ways:
>
> - browse by document number, or by term
> - view documents / copy to clipboard
> - retrieve a ranked list of most frequent terms execute a search, and      browse the results
> - analyze search results
> - selectively delete       documents from the    index
> - reconstruct the original document fields,       edit them and       re-insert to the index
> - optimize indexes
> - open indexes consisting of multiple parts, and/or located on Hadoop      filesystem
> - and much more...

Simply open the index files and you will have a peek on how properties and data were tokenized.
As reported in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827305/display-the-actual-index-field) it could be easily used also for SolR indexes.

Comment: Hey abarisone, thanks for your prompt response. I am actually trying to retrieve it programatically. So, are you aware about any API or services using which I can access them?

Comment: Did you check [SolrJ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ)?